# php curl with proxy returning blank page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch the content of a web page and for this I am using curl with proxy IP. Here is the code that I have written but it returns me a blank page. No error and no warning. Any help on this would save my life.

```
$url='http://in.yahoo.com/';

  $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) 
            AppleWebKit/532.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
            Chrome/4.0.233.0 Safari/532.4";

$loginpassw = 'xyz:123';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '82.143.88.122:8080');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $loginpassw);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $data;
```

Can't exactly understand where the issue is ...

Comment: Do you get anything from `curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois...yes I used but it shows me a blank page only

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of echo. If you still get a blank white page, make sure error reporting is enabled.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois...yes I got this error while using var_dump...bool(false)

Comment: yes...now I am getting the CURL_ERROR...its showing...Curl error: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds what does it meant for?

Comment: The connection timed out after 10 seconds. I think your proxy takes too long to pick up the connection, you could try changing the timeout to a higher value.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois...i added this line...curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120000); after  this am getting this message only...Curl error: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Comment: Did you also increase `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`? PS: The value is in seconds, just like `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois...now I got this error message...Curl error: Failed to connect to 82.143.88.122 port 8080

Comment: Well, your proxy doesn't work, that's the problem here.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois...yes thats what i was fearing off...thanks for helping me troubleshooting...many thanks...

Comment: If you must to authenticate to be able to connect you can use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth); $proxy = 'IP:PORT';
$proxyauth = 'user:password';

Comment: @CharlotteDunois...I just deactivated Firewall...now am getting this error...Curl error: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT